# Secure boot violation

Tags: windows, bios, uefi

При загрузке возникает ошибка Secure Boot Violation (Invalid signature detected. Check Secure Boot Policy in Setup). При нажатии ок все корректно загружается.

Как исправить?

Comment: Включить безопасную загрузку.

Comment: Secure boot? Она включена, если ее выключить, то винда вообще не загружается